# Morphism that is surjective on PID points is surjective on every Dedekind domain?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $f: X=\Bbb A^n \rightarrow Y=\Bbb A^m $ be a morphism between affine spaces over an algebraically closed field $k$. Assume $f: X(R) \rightarrow Y(R)$ is surjective for any PID $R$ over $k$, under which condition can we assure that it's also surjective over any Dedekind domain over $k$? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: what are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @YCor I am interested in general case, to simplify the notion here I only consider affine spaces. Thank you, now it's fixed.

Comment: The "Weak Approximation Conjecture" (which is a theorem in many cases) says that a morphism $f:\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathbb{A}^1$ of degree $d<n$ is surjective on PID points if and only if the smooth locus of $f$ surjects onto $\mathbb{A}^1$, i.e., every fiber has a nonempty open subset that is smooth.  On the other hand, surjectivity for the Dedekind domain $R=k[\mathbb{A}^1]$ implies that there exists a section $g:\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^n$.  This is a very strong analogue of existence of integral points.

Comment: @JasonStarr I'm confused by what you write because it doesn't seem to draw any distinction between PIDs and Dedekind domains, because $k[\mathbb A^1]$ is a Dedkind domain. In fact in the $m=1$ case, assuming surjectivity on PID-valued points, there is a global section, implying that the map is surjective on $R$-points for every ring.

Comment: @WillSawin.  You are correct.  I was reading "PID points" as "DVR points".  Weak approximation is surjectivity for DVR points, not for PID points.  Sorry about the mistake.